# SBT - Override testOnly

Tags: sbt, scalatest

For `testOnly` in sbt I want to use specific `testOptions` (so the task `test` has different `testOptions`) and also I want to set a environment variable..

Any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by introducing a new scope `Diagnose`:

```
lazy val Diagnose = config("diagnose") extend Test
lazy val diagnoseSettings = inConfig(Build.Diagnose)(Defaults.testTasks ++ Seq(testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-oD"), envVars := Map("TEST_LOG_LEVEL" -> "debug")))
```

Then I use it at a project in conjuction with these settings

```
val p = (project in file("project")).configs(Build.Diagnose).settings(Build.diagnoseSettings).settings(testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-W", "5", "2"), testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-oNCXEHLOPQRM"))
```

Now when I run `sbt test` it will show only the failed tests. When you want to see why it failed you can use `sbt diagnose:testOnly test-class`